# How to address this warning generated by crashlytics / fabric?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, twitter-fabric, google-fabric

Here is what I know/do:

- I am importing Fabric via a pod.
- The build script for Fabric is the last one
- It is set to generate a dsysm

DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT should be set to dwarf-with-dsym for all configurations.

This could also be a timing issue, make sure the Fabric run script build phase is the last build phase and no other scripts have moved the dSYM from the location Xcode generated it. Unable to process myapp.app.dSYM at path /Users/no-one/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ahatoktzxteqbcaohqnktdtfczxr/Build/Products/Debug-appletvos/myapp.app.dSYM

Make sure your project build settings are generating a dSYM file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go into your target's Build Settings and then type in `DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT` into the Search Bar that appears in the top right.

It looks like this:
[image: How To Find Debug Information Format from Build Settings]

And you can choose "Dwarf With Dsym" from the pop-up menu.

Comment: thank you - I thought that having it set to Dwarf was sufficient